# Why does the C−H bond dissociation energy vary in a homologous series of primary alcohols?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, energy, alcohols, enthalpy

Specifically, for the primary carbon atom in the alcohol. Here is bond dissociation energy (BDE) data from chapter three of Luo's *Comprehensive handbook of chemical bond energies* [1] (**boldface** refers to dissociated atom):

$$
\begin{array}{llc}
\hline
\text{Compound} & \text{The broken bonds} & \mathrm{BDE}/\pu{kJ mol-1} \\
\hline
\text{Methanol} & \ce{\textbf{H}-CH2OH} & 401.92±0.63 \\
\textit{n}\text{-Ethanol} & \ce{\textbf{H}-CH2CH2OH} & 410.0±8.4 \\
\textit{n}\text{-Propanol} & \ce{\textbf{H}-CH2CH2CH2OH} & 406.3±8.4 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Many websites like [Chemistry LibreTexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Fundamentals/Homolytic_C-H_Bond_Dissociation_Energies_of_Organic_Molecules) describe how the average C−H BDE is different from the BDEs in specific compounds. Some explain how *the hybridisation of the C−H bond has an effect* or *whether you're considering the primary, secondary, or tertiary carbon* makes a difference.

In the case of the homologous series of primary alcohols though, the hybridisation for the C−H bond is always the same. Also, I'm only using values from the primary carbons. I checked the *bond lengths for the C−H bond* on the primary carbon for all the alcohols on [Molview](https://molview.org/?cid=20189186) too. They're all the same.

What other factors can influence the variation in the BDEs?

#### References

1. Luo, Y.-R. *Comprehensive Handbook of Chemical Bond Energies*; CRC press, **2007**. ISBN 978-0-8493-7366-4.

---

An idea my chemistry teacher described:

**Perhaps, the intermolecular forces could influence the bond enthalpy between C-H bonds?**

For example, as the homologous series of alcohols gains more methylene groups, *the London
Dispersion Forces (LDF) between each alcohol molecule increase*. So let's say you're heating up the alcohols to break the C-H bonds. In the process, some of the heat energy will go towards overcoming the LDF's attraction between molecules. Then, additional energy would be needed to break the C-H bonds after that.

At the same time though, you would have to consider the effect of *decreasing polarity of the alcohol molecules and decreasing dipole-dipole forces*. **Does anyone know what kind of data could be used to quantify the strength of these different effects?**

Comment: Think about the inductive effect

Comment: There is a big error in measurement for ethanol and propanol.

Comment: I wouldn't trust Molview data on equal bond length though. Molview only roughly *predicts* the values. Experimental data collected by using, say, microwave spectrometry or x-ray diffraction (or even better, neutron diffraction since we are looking for hydrogen atoms), will show some deviation.

Comment: Better think about products - what radical you get.